# Activity has leaked IntentReceiver AutoNightModeManager registered on AlertDialog creation

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alertdialog, android-night-mode

I have an activity with an `AlertDialog` created on the `onCreate` method.

When the activity is destroyed, I get this exception:

```
E/ActivityThread: Activity com.materight.turkdroid.ui.activities.LoginActivity has leaked IntentReceiver androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AutoNightModeManager$1@18c886c that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.materight.turkdroid.ui.activities.LoginActivity has leaked IntentReceiver androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AutoNightModeManager$1@18c886c that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1429)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1210)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1476)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1449)
        ...
        at com.materight.turkdroid.ui.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:74)
        ...
```

The `line 74` where the error is thrown is where the dialog is created:

```
        pendingDialog = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setTitle(R.string.pending_purchase_title)
                .setMessage(R.string.pending_purchase_content)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.close, (d, which) -> finishAffinity())
                .create();
```

I've already tried to add `pendingDialog.dismiss()` in `onDestroy`, `finish` and `finishAffinity` methods with no results. The dialog is not always shown, so maybe the `dismiss` method doesn't work correctly in this case?

What cause this exception and how can I solve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trials, I've finally found a solution.

Symply by using `finishAffinity()` instead of `finish()` to close the current activity the issue disappeared.